# Гречка or Гречиха

Tags: грамматика

Reading a few Wikipedia articles I come across different ways to spell buckwheat. One is Гречка (which is what I use when talking about buckwheat) and Гречиха (which I have never heard of before). What is the difference between the two words?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Buckwheat *plant* is called **гречиха**. It is cultivated for its *grain-like seeds* called **греча** or **гречка** (**гречневая крупа**) which we cook. The cooked buckwheat is called **гречка, греча, гречневая каша.** There are also *гречневый продел* (which is grated buckwheat grain) and *гречневая мука* (buckwheat flour) used for cooking.

Comment: In Ukraine, the speakers of Russian never use the name _гречневый продел_, and most of them don't even know what it is. _Гречневый продел_ is called _гречневая сечка_ in Ukraine, just a little remark on regional varieties of Russian.